# QT: QDesktopWidget is deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: qt

I need to find the pixel resolution of each screen my desktop app is connected to. The QDesktopWidget will do this. The docs say that it is obsolete, but they don't recommend what to use instead.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `QGuiApplication::screens` to get a list of `QScreen` objects.

Comment: [QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop)